# $F_{n}$ converge in distribution to $F$, and $A$ is closed set, then $F_{n}|_{A}$ uniformly converge to $F|_{A}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm solving some problems in Billingsley's Convergence of probability measures.

Problem is

> Assume that $F_n$ converge in distribution to $F$, and if $F$ is
> continuous at each point of a closed set $A$, then $$\sup_{x\in
> A}|{F_{n}(x) - F(x)}| \to 0$$

At first glance, it is similar to  Glivenko-Cantelli theorem, but It is slightly different. I cannot get any gut feeling to use the condition about closed set.

Thanks.

Comment: Which chapter is this problem part of? What results are discussed in that chapter? You may have to use those results, so it is better if you tell us.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon This chapter is 1-3. Thank you. (Before this chapter, they treat about what is weakly convergence and tightness.)

Comment: Thanks for that, I've already upvoted you. I will try to answer your question but first I need to think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mu_n$ be the probability measure represented by $F_n$ and $\mu$ be the probability measure represented by $F$.

Pick any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $F$ is continuous

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\big((-\infty,x]\setminus(-\infty,x-1/n]\big)=\lim_n F(x)-F(x-1/n)=0.$$
Therefore $\mu(\{x\})=0$. Now $x$ is the boundary of $(-\infty,x]$, which is therefore a $\mu$-continuity set. By the Portmanteau theorem,

$$F(x)=\mu\big((-\infty,x]\big)=\lim_n \mu_n\big((-\infty,x]\big)=\lim_n F_n(x).$$

So $\lim_n F_n(x)=F(x)$ for *all* $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

You can now use the monotonicity of $F$ as in the proof of the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem to show that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot follow your proof. $F$ is continuous at $x$ implies that $(-\infty, F(x)]$ is $\mu$-continuity set, but it does not imply that $F_n$ converges pointwise to $F$. Can you give me more specific process?

Comment: @probafds123 I added some details.

Comment: But the condition of problem says that $F$ is continuous at some closed set $A$, not continuous at all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: OK. I got it. Using continuity points, we can do similar process as Glivenko-Cantelli. Thank you!